# Unable to Run Selenium with Firefox (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping, geckodriver

I am completely unable to get Selenium (3.0.1) to work with Firefox (50.1.0) after the update. Here is the code that I am running with the associated errors:

```
from selenium import webdriver

website = 'www.google.com'

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get(website)
```

This gives the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have read numerous posts talking about the need to add various executable files to my PATH variable in order to run Selenium, but I have thus far completely failed. My current PATH variable is the following:

```
$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I have not been able to successfully append the firefox or geckodriver executable files. It appears to be there already (I've copied the executable to '/usr/local/bin', and it's still giving me the same error. Any and all help is greatly appreciated (Mac OS X user)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: I've tried following those exact steps in various forms and none of them have worked so far.

Comment: I've also added the geckodriver.exe to the path, this still has not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, given a week of not working on this, then re-googling the problem, I was able to solve it. The hint that helped me was given in this link:

[Selenium in Python on Mac - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435983/selenium-in-python-on-mac-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

I wasn't adding the geckodriver.exe file to the right path. When I downloaded and moved the file to my anaconda bin, it worked just fine:

mv geckodriver /anaconda/bin  #after navigating to my downloads

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can have to install geckodriver and add it yo your execution path. Use the following bash command to install the latest geckodriver:

```
which geckodriver || (wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.14.0/geckodriver-v0.14.0-linux64.tar.gz -O /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz && tar -C /opt -xzf /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz && chmod 755 /opt/geckodriver && ln -fs /opt/geckodriver /usr/bin/geckodriver && ln -fs /opt/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver)
```

This will install geckodriver v0.14.0 for you. I tested it with the latests firefox 51.0.1

Answer (score 0):

you can append path to the PATH variable at run time as well.

```
import sys
```

`sys,path.append('the path where the file is stored')`